# How to send video or image select from camera button through email using dispatch queue

Tags: ios, swift

I want to send video or image in camera button clicked through email, image is sent successfully but video not be send. i am using this stuff of coding. is there any solution for this.

```
 @IBAction func forwardButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if type == .add {
            if contact != nil {
                MailMessageStore.shared.sendEmail() { (success) in }
            } else {
               showError()
            }
        } else {
            let subject = "TOCA Note-\(contact.fullName ?? "-")"
            let body = "Export from TOCA\n Contact Name: \(contact.fullName ?? "-")\n Company: \(contact.companyName ?? "-")\n Notes from \(notes.date!)\n\n Note:\n\(notes.notes!)"
            SVProgressHUD.show()
            print(self.notes.audio)
            print(self.notes.image)
            print(self.notes.video)


            dispatch_main_after(0.001, {
                MailMessageStore.shared.sendEmail(emailSubject: subject, emailBody: body, imageData: self.notes.imageURL != nil ? try?  Data(contentsOf: self.notes.imageURL): nil, audioData: self.notes.audioURL != nil ? try? Data(contentsOf: self.notes.audioURL) : nil, videoData: self.notes.videoURL != nil ? try? Data(contentsOf: self.notes.videoURL) : nil) { (success) in
                    if success! {
                        SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "Email sent successfuly")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```